# How to perform a tolerant name search in SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, search, android-sqlite

I have a DB with 4 columns,

```
|ID|CATEGORY|NAME|NATION|
```

And have a search method that simply makes a `SELECT WHERE NAME LIKE SEARCHKEYWORD`, to return the searched item,
but this isn't very functional, because the keyword must be identical to the name to find something.

How to perform a more efficient search, tolerant to little differences between the keyword and the stored item?

Comment: With ends-with and contains searches, the query loses efficiency because an index cannot be used and the query must scan every row in the table.

Comment: If permitted in Android, SQLite also has a GLOB operator. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:
`SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE lower(NAME) LIKE '%SEARCHKEYWORD%'`
And always make SEARCHKEYWORD in lower case.

Comment: if Name contains spaces doesn't works, for example name Mustang GT, keyword mustang gt... returns empty query

Comment: I believe it is because cases doesn't match. I edited the answer. Please try the modified solution and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Use this Query to select what ever you giving input

```
SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE NAME LIKE '%SEARCHKEYWORD%'
```

or use first letters

```
SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE NAME LIKE 'SEARCHKEYWORD%'
```

from last

```
SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE NAME LIKE '%SEARCHKEYWORD'
```

Comment: in your code miss the ' , for this reason i got the error, 
however if Name contains spaces doesn't works, for example name Mustang GT, keyword mustang gt... returns empty query